# I'm trying to use RMySQL to perform search on imdb, but does not seem to get the tables right

Tags: rmysql

I'm new to RMySQL. I'm trying to do an assignment based on the code in this page: https://beanumber.github.io/sds192/lab-sql.html and got stuck after I ran the first few lines:

```
 library(mdsr)
 library(RMySQL)
 db <- dbConnect_scidb(dbname = "imdb")
 class(db)
 db %>%
   dbGetQuery("SELECT * FROM kind_type;")
```

Below is my output:

```
[1] "MySQLConnection"
attr(,"package")
[1] "RMySQL"
>  db %>%
+    dbGetQuery("SELECT * FROM kind_type;")
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
could not run statement: Table 'imdb.kind_type' doesn't exist
```

I also tried to list the tables in db and below is the output:

```
> dbListTables(db)
character(0)
```

I greatly appreciate help on this issue.